# Emails bouncing - 454 TLS not available due to temporary reason

Tags: email-server, ubuntu-16.04, email-bounces

I'm trying to work out why I've started getting emails bounced back to me:

> Delivery incomplete There was a temporary problem while delivering
>   your message to mail@educationusingpowerpoint.co.uk. Gmail will retry
>   for 47 more hours. You'll be notified if the delivery fails
>   permanently. The response was: 454 TLS currently unavailable

I've done a bit of research online, and they suggest it could be the SSL that has expired. I've checked it, and I can't see any expired certificates.

Any other suggestions as to what I can try? It's doing it on 2 different sites on the same server.

**UPDATE:** When testing here, it fails miserably:

- https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/educationusingpowerpoint.co.uk
- https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/thecostumerooms.co.uk
- https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/rieducazionevisiva.com

I'm just not too sure why though. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what to try? It was all working fine, so I'm assuming a LetsEncrypt certificate has expired, but I'm not sure which one / how to track it down

Thanks

Comment: Try changing your outgoing mail SMTP port from 25 to 465(SSL), that seems to do the trick for people with similar issues.

Comment: @JayMcTee thanks, this is going out from my gmail account though, so not sure I can even change that?

Comment: It doesn't look like any of those mail servers are even reachable...do you control these?

Comment: @NathanC - thanks for the reply. Yeah I think you are kinda right. I'm wondering if the DNS is wrong. Currently I have the MX records set to point to maik.domain.com, but I'm wondering if they should be admin.steampunkjunkies.com (which validates correctly)

Comment: @NathanC - I've just done some tweaks to point the MX to admin.steampunkjunkies.com. I guess I will have to wait and see how it works after its updated (I've also changed it to TTL = 5 mins, so I can test changes quicker in the future)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it. Duh, can't believe I was that stupid! It's weird how it worked before, but then suddenly stopped working. Anyway, for someone else who gets something like this, check what this tool returns: https://ssl-tools.net/mailservers/ . If you get any errors (like mine, with a non-connection, and then a mis-matched SSL cert), you at least have a clue as to where to start :))