# How can I automate letsencrypt certificates with apache and standalone authentication?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I have many letsencrypt certificates with apache authentification. They are very well updated automatically.

I have one certificate (xmpp), that has standalone authentification. This one always fails because I have to stop apache in order to use it.

Now, to solve my problem I could add a cronjob that stops apache, runs `certbot certonly -d xmpp.host.de --standalone --non-interactive` and restarts apache. The problem is that in 99% I'm stopping apache without reason, because the cert isn't expired.

I didn't find a really good solution to that problem. How do you solve that?

Comment: Why don't you use dns authentication instead? or configure a vhost in apache that allows you to update the certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a vhost in apache for `xmpp.example.com` that is used by certbot for authentication. You don't have to place any actual content there. I use this to renew the certificate for dovecot.

I then use the renew-hook of certbot to restart or reload the correct service, depending on the domain that has been renewed. You can see a basic script for this [in my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/868900/email-server-configuration-still-complaining-the-connection-isnt-secure/868919#868919).