# Cerbot for both NGINX and Redis

Tags: nginx, ssl, redis, certbot

I'm running `ubuntu` with both `NGINX` (443) and `Redis` (6379) ports exposed separately on the same machine,
I want them both to use `TLS` and for that I'm using `Cerbot`.

From time to time `Cerbot` automatically renew, and it immediately makes `NGINX` to reload itself for renewal to take effect.. Will `Redis` do the same?

Is this command valid for `Redis` as well as `NGINX` by giving `Redis` the same key and cert location?

```
sudo certbot --nginx
```

It's important that long living server would not run into error when renewing occurred and will reload them on both without the need to restart `ubuntu`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email server configuration still complaining the connection isn't secure](https://serverfault.com/questions/868900/email-server-configuration-still-complaining-the-connection-isnt-secure)